# Where can Mockito 2.3.3 Jar be downloaded?

Tags: java, mockito

Silly question, but I am trying to download Mockito Test Framework Version 2.3.3, but the official website https://bintray.com/mockito/maven/mockito/2.3.3 doesn't provide a download link.

Also Google didn't reveal any valuable result.

Can anybody provide a reliable download source for a recent version of Mockito?

Comment: The official website? bintray.com is the official website for mockito? Not really and your question is offtopic anyway.

Comment: [here](https://dl.bintray.com/mockito/maven/org/mockito/mockito-core/2.3.3/). Download is on the top right of the page...

Comment: why don't you use maven?

Comment: A google search for 'Mockito' brings up the http://site.mockito.org/ website. Front and center, there is a link to download and a link to Maven central.

Comment: It is a silly question. It's even sillier to claim that "Google doesn't return anything useful".

Comment: Guys, thanks for downvoting. :-( The link I pasted indeed stems from the official site (http://site.mockito.org/) and is the link target from the prominently positioned download link. Of course I tried this. I used Google quite heavily, still it didn't turn out the proper result. Many thanks to @mammago for the actual link. If you like to, post it as an answer.

Comment: "Silly question"... Yep

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, i'm really glad this question is here. i *still* have no idea where the link for the 2.3.5 download is, whoever runs mockito should really fix this!

Comment: This is far from a silly question. No we don't use maven, and I want to download it, but they refuse to provide a freaking link!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you follow the [Mockito documentation](http://site.mockito.org/#how) and use a dependency manager. In there example they use gadle, since you mentioned Maven, here the dependency I used with maven:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the latest version from the Maven repository (so not 2.3.3), however if  you are not using a dependency manager, here a link to [download the jar](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.mockito%20AND%20a:mockito-core&core=gav) - on the right of the version you want click the download.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!